# pg_restore fails on zlib compressed dump

Tags: backup, compression, restore, postgresql

Created a dump of a postgresql (windows version 9.3 or 9.4) database with the command:

```
C:\>pg_dump -U user -Z 6 database > db.dump
```

restoring it with psql or pg_restore fails:

```
C:\>psql.exe -U postgres db < db.dump  
ERROR: invalid byte sequence for encoding "UTF8": 0x8b

C:\>pg_restore.exe -U postgres -d db < db.dump  
pg_restore: [archiver] input file does not appear to be a valid archive

C:\>pg_restore.exe -U postgres -d db --format=c db.dump
pg_restore: [archiver] did not find magic string in file header
```

trying to verify the file:

```
user:~$ file db.dump
db.dump: gzip compressed data, from NTFS filesystem (NT)

user:~$ zcat db.dump
gzip: db.dump: invalid compressed data--format violated
```

So how do I restore this compressed dump ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: run `fixgz` on the compressed dump.

```
fixgz.exe bad.gz fixed.gz
```

Long answer:
So if you used `pg_dump` with `--compresss` or `-Z` without specifying custom format option (`-Fc`), what you actually get is a compressed file in ASCII mode instead of BINARY mode.

Quoting from [The gzip home page](https://web.archive.org/web/20180624175230/http://www.gzip.org/#faq1):

> 99.9% of the problems with *gzip*
>   are due to file transfers done in ASCII mode instead of BINARY mode. 
>   In particular, gopher is known to corrupt binary files
>   by considering them as ASCII. 
>   Make sure that your local copy of the file
>   has *exactly* the same byte size as the original.
>
> If you have transferred a file in ASCII mode and you no longer have
>   access to the original, you can try the program [`fixgz`](https://web.archive.org/web/20180624175230/http://www.gzip.org/fixgz.c)
>   to remove the extra CR (carriage return) bytes inserted by the transfer. 
>   A Windows 9x/NT/2000/ME/XP binary is [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20180624175230/http://www.gzip.org/fixgz.zip). 
>   But there is absolutely no guarantee that this will actually fix your file. 
>   Conclusion: never transfer binary files in ASCII mode.

[Note that the "[here](https://web.archive.org/web/20180624175230/http://www.gzip.org/fixgz.zip)" link
is a link directly to a downloadable ZIP file
that includes the (`.c`) source, the (`.exe`) executable, and a `README`.]

Comment: Both -Fc and -Z without -Fc produce a binary file. A transfer tool used to copy that file from one machine to another must leave it unmodified. The tool and option you used to copy the file, which the question does not mention, is apparently the root cause of the failure here.

Comment: The link in the original answer seems to be no longer operational.  At the moment, at least, it can be found via https://web.archive.org/web/20180624175352/http://www.gzip.org/fixgz.zip.

Comment: One has to wonder why the gzip people *removed* `fixgz` from [their home page](http://www.gzip.org) — is there a problem with it? Is there something better?

Answer (score 1):

The file that you have created is a gzipped plain-text file.  To restore that, use something like

```
zcat db.dump | psql ...
```

If you want a non-plain-text dump, you should use the option `-Fc` when running `pg_dump`.

Comment: Correct, it is a gzipped plain-text file, though I already showed that zcat fails. Host machine is now dead and I need to get the data back so my only option is to restore/unzip this file